# css popup effecting html layout

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am triggering a css driven popup on click, and I simply do not want it to effect the ui.

In the example below, I have it auto appearing to show the effect on the layout.

Can someone tell me how to alter the popup so it does not effect the html underneath? Thanks.

```css
div.callout {
  background-color: #FFF;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444, #444);
  position: relative;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;
  margin: 25px;
  min-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #0079C2;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  /*box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;*/
}
.callout::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 0.8em solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
}
.callout.right::before {
  left: -20px;
  top: 40%;
  border-right: 10px solid #0079C2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table class="table" style="margin:0 auto; width:100%; align:center;">
    <col width="25%">
      <col width="25%">
        <col width="25%">
          <col width="25%">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>group A</th>
                <th>group B</th>
                <th>group C</th>
                <th>group D</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p><a href="" onclick="">click for more info</a>
                    <br>
                    <a href="" id="rate">++display popup++</a>
                  </p>

                  <div id="flag" class="callout right" style="">


                    <iframe id="frame" src="https://yahoo.com" scrolling="no" width="200px" height="250px" frameborder="0">

                    </iframe>

                  </div>

                  <p style="text-align: left;">
                    <img src="images/1.png" alt="1.png" style="margin: 0px;" />​
                    <br/>
                  </p>

                </td>
                <td>
                  <p><a href="" onclick="openFit()">click to learn</a>
                    <br>click to learn</p>
                  <p style="text-align: left;">
                    <img src="images/2.png" alt="2.png" style="margin: 0px; " />​
                    <br/>
                  </p>

                </td>
                <td>
                  <p>click to learn</br>
                    Earn your pOints​​​​​​​</p>
                  <p style="text-align: left;">
                    <img src="images/3.png" alt="3.png" style="margin: 0px; " />​
                    <br/>
                  </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p>click to learn
                    <br>Earn your Points​​​​​​​</p>
                  <p style="text-align: left;">
                    <img src="4.png" alt="ace_4.png" style="margin: 0px; " />​
                    <br/>
                  </p>
                </td>

              </tr>
            </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `position: relative` on the pop-up, use `position: absolute`.

```
 div.callout {
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444, #444);
    position: absolute; /*ADJUSTED*/
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;
    margin: 25px;
    min-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #0079C2;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
    /*box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;*/
  }
```

With `position: relative` an element remains in the normal flow of the document. In other words, it continues to take up space and impacts the layout.

With `position: absolute` the element is removed from the normal flow and surrounding elements act as though it doesn't exist.

Once the element is absolutely positioned, you can use the CSS offset properties (`top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right`) to move it around.

Keep in mind, an absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to its [***nearest positioned ancestor***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning). Therefore, make sure to add `position: relative` to the element you want to set as the containing block for the pop-up. Otherwise, the abspos element will by default be positioned relative to the viewport.

https://jsfiddle.net/vdxhnfsp/1/